# Работа в нескольких процессах одновременно

Tags: c#

Задача: в асинхронном режиме опросить несколько gprs модемов.

На главной форме (WinForms)имеются два списка типа `ListView` - один со списком COM- портов, к которым подключены модемы, (к компьютеру подключен пул модемов) другой - со списком телефонных номеров для этих модемов.

Опрос пытаюсь провести в следующей процедуре:

```
void RunProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Ip=lvCOM.Items.Count;
    int Jp=listModem.Items.Count;
    int n=0;
    string cTelN;
    string cPortN=string.Empty;;
    if(Ip==0) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Нет ни одного порта с подключенным модемом!","Ошибка!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    if(Jp==0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Список с телефонными номерами модемов пуст!","Ошибка!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    do
    {

        for(int i=0;i<Jp-1;i++)
        {
            //Перебор по телефонным номерам
            cTelN=listModem.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
            if(listModem.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text=="Свободен")
            {
                if(listModem.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    //помечаем номер модема, как находящийся в обработке
                    Invoke(new Action(()=>listModem.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text="Работает"));
                    Invoke(new Action(listModem.Refresh));
                }
                else
                {
                    listModem.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text="Работает";
                    listModem.Refresh();
                }
                //перебор портов
                //Проверяем, есть ли подготовленные COM - порты
                int nb=0;
                do
                {
                    for(var j=0; j<lvCOM.Items.Count;j++)
                    {
                        if(lvCOM.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text=="Ожидает")
                            nb++;
                    }
                }
                while(nb==0);//если свободных портов нет - повторяем цикл
                //Выбираем свободный порт
                for(var k=0; k<lvCOM.Items.Count;k++)
                {
                    if(lvCOM.Items[k].SubItems[1].Text=="Ожидает")
                    {
                        cPortN=lvCOM.Items[k].Text;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            int indC=0;
            foreach(ListViewItem lviC in lvCOM.Items)
            {
                if(lviC.SubItems[0].Text==cPortN)
                {
                    indC=lviC.Index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //отмечаем выбранный порт как находящийся в работе
            if(lvCOM.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(()=>lvCOM.Items[indC].SubItems[1].Text="Занят"));
                Invoke(new Action(lvCOM.Refresh));
            }
            else
            {
                lvCOM.Items[indC].SubItems[1].Text="Занят";
                lvCOM.Refresh();
            }
            //var tRun=new Task(()=>proc.ModemProc("COM3","89141502656"));
            //Запускаем процесс обработки запроса к модему
            var tRun=new Task(()=>proc.ModemProc(cPortN,cTelN));
            tRun.Start();
        }
        n++;
    }
    while (n<5);//Максимальное число опросов
}
```

В процедуре обработки запроса к модему имеются вызовы для отображения хода выполнения задачи:

```
public clsResult ModemProc(string portNum, string telNum)
{
    var cRes=new clsResult();
    portNumber=portNum;
    TelNum=telNum;
    cRes.TNum=telNum;

    // Открываем COM - порт
    try
    {
        _port = new SerialPort(portNum)
        {
            BaudRate = _speed,
            Parity = _stParity,
            WriteTimeout = _tsT,
            ReadTimeout = _rsT,
            StopBits = _stBits,
            DataBits = _dBits,
            Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
            DiscardNull=true
        };
        if(!_port.IsOpen)
       //                try
       //                {
        //{
            _port.Open();
            var na=new NotifyArgs(1,1,"Порт " +portNum+" открыт.",0, 
            portNumber, TelNum);    
            onStr.Invoke(na);

            _port.DataReceived+=_port_DataResived;
            int pRes=ModemConnect(telNum);
```

и так далее..

Для отслеживания процесса здесь имеется событие, оповещающее главную форму экземпляром класса `NotifyArgs`

В главной форме события обрабатываются и выводятся в визуальной форме

```
void onProcStr(NotifyArgs na)
{
    SetRun(na);
}

public void SetRun(NotifyArgs runResult)
{
    if (lstRun.InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new Action(()=>ChCOMText(runResult)));
    else
        ChCOMText(runResult);
}
```

`ChCOMText` - процедура, выводящая информацию в текстовое окно.

Все протестировано, по отдельности работает отлично, пытаюсь связать все в кучу. Для асинхронного режима рабoты выбрал BackgroundWorker

Код кнопки "Начать"

```
void BtnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstRes.Clear();
    proc=new clsProcess();
    proc.onStr+=onProcStr;
    proc.onEnd+=onEndProc;

    bw.DoWork+=RunProcess;
    bwRun.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Теперь самое главное: при нажатии на кнопку "Начать" все виснет наглухо. Бьюсь над проблемой третий день.. Может кто-то подскажет где я туплю и что делать..

На будущее запланирована еще кнопка отмены операции и обработка ошибок..

Comment: 1)Зачем использовать BackgroundWorker? Это устаревшая штука. 2) А вы пробовалb ставить дебагер на паузу? Может у вас где-то взаимоблокировка, бессконечный цикл и все такое...

Comment: А модемы разве не имеют закрепленного за каждым свой отдельный COM порт? Зачем вы ищите свободный порт, а не свободный модем?

Comment: Visual Studio подарила вам чудесный отладчик, которым можно подключиться к повисшему процессу, и в Debug -> Windows -> Threads посмотреть какой поток приложения чем сейчас занят. Проблему вы найдёте существенно быстрее, чем за три дня медитации. ;)